# Custom list definition shows title even if it is not declared in schema

Tags: list, list-definition

I created an own list definition with list instance in the project.
I described all the fields in the schema which should be shown. ANd it is ok, after deploying when i visit the list it show all mine fields, but when i click on add new item, between all those fields, first i show is field 'Title', and i dont understand why it comes there, and how to get rid of it?

Thanks for the help.

Here is the schema for the list definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Custom - CustomListDef" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/Custom-CustomListDef" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{93CF7259-2031-49B8-94E2-714A786F67AA}" Name="ID" Type="Text" DisplayName="ID" Group="V" Required="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE" />
      <Field ID="{A122D632-9D29-47FE-84A1-8609B94AF86C}" Name="Auteur" Type="Text" DisplayName="Auteur" Group="V" Required="FALSE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE" />
      <Field ID="{813B6A47-A0AC-46DD-912E-CBABE499D617}" Name="Reference" Type="Text" DisplayName="Reference" Group="V" Required="FALSE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE" />
      <Field ID="{776862E6-17F7-4CC6-9D70-6C63C6895887}" Name="TypeDoc" Type="Text" DisplayName="Type Document" Group="V" Required="FALSE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE" />
      <Field ID="{32820B0D-5084-4D44-8CFB-598F7B922092}" Name="CreationDate" Type="Text" DisplayName="Creation Date" Group="V" Required="FALSE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE" />
    </Fields>
    <Views>
      <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="IDMetallurgyNuance"/>
          <FieldRef Name="AuteurMetallurgyNuance" />
          <FieldRef Name="ReferenceMetallurgyNuance" />
          <FieldRef Name="TypeDocMetallurgyNuance" />
          <FieldRef Name="CreationDateMetallurgyNuance" />
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_ONET_HOME)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="IDMetallurgyNuance"/>
          <FieldRef Name="AuteurMetallurgyNuance" />
          <FieldRef Name="ReferenceMetallurgyNuance" />
          <FieldRef Name="TypeDocMetallurgyNuance" />
          <FieldRef Name="CreationDateMetallurgyNuance" />
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a built in field.  Try adding the following to your Content Type:

```
<FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Hidden="TRUE" Required="FALSE" DisplayName="_hidden" />
```

Ian.

Comment: You mean to schema of the defenition?